# How can I run `gradlew clean build` in all subdirs starting with given prefix?

Tags: zsh, xargs

I have multiple project directories `project-one`, `project-two`, `different-project`. I want to run `./gradlew clean build` within all these directories that begin with `project-`. Can I use `xargs` to do that? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're tagging with `zsh`:

```
for dir (project-*/gradlew(N*:h)) (cd $dir && ./gradlew clean build)
```

That looks for the *executable* (`*`) `gradlew` files in subdirs of the current  working directory whose name start with `project-` (would also consider symlinks to directories there), takes their `h`ead to result in the directories themselves, and `for` each `dir`, start  a subshell `(...)` inside which we `c`hange the current working `d`irectory to that `dir` run `./gradlew clean build` if `cd` was successful.

Doing it with `xargs` would be painful. One reason you may want to do it would be if your `xargs` was the one from the GNU project and you wanted to run a few `gradlew`s in parallel.

For instance.

```
xargs -r0 -P4 -n1 -a <(print -rNC1 project-*/gradlew(N*:h)) \
  sh -c 'cd "$1" && exec ./gradlew clean build' sh
```

would run up to `4` `sh` in `P`arallel, each of them taking `1` of those matching dirs, `cd`ing into it and running `./gradlew clean build`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the individual substeps! Does the syntax with the parens after `gradlew` have a name? I'd like to read up on that.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. It's a *glob modifier* and the `N` prevents unintuitive behaviour on empty directories.